# ¿Cómo enviar un objeto con Ajax y Json?

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy intentando enviar un arreglo de objetos con el formato Json y Ajax de esta manera:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ProbarDatos", "Charlas")',
        data: { prueba: JSON.stringify ([{ p1: "perro", p2: "gato" }, { p3: "pez", p4: "raton" }]) },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (rpta) {
        alert(rpta);
        console.log(rpta);
    },
    error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Y lo estoy recibiendo en mi controlador de esta manera:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ProbarDatos(string[] prueba)
    {

        return Json(prueba);

    }
```

Y el resultado es este en la consola:

```
    ["[{"p1":"perro","p2":"gato"},{"p3":"pez","p4":"raton"}]"]
     0: "[{"p1":"perro","p2":"gato"},{"p3":"pez","p4":"raton"}]"
     length: 1
     __proto__: Array(0)
```

Como verán, me esta devolviendo todo como si fuera un objeto, cuando en realidad son 2 objetos. ¿Cómo podría hacer para poder recibir los 2 objetos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero tienes que formatear tu json  https://jsoneditoronline.org/

```
 var data = {"uno": { "p1": "perro", "p2": "gato" },"dos": { "p3": "pez", "p4": "raton" } }
```